# Как можно сократить отдельный кусок кода

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".surfboard__images__img");
var movingline = document.querySelector(".surfboards__main__information__choice_line__current");
var choices = document.querySelectorAll(".surfboards__main__information__choice__p");
var slider = document.querySelector(".surfboards__main__information__text__slider");
var board = document.querySelectorAll(".board");
var sliderCounter = 0;
var sliderBack = document.querySelector(".surfboards__slider_arrows__back");
var sliderForward = document.querySelector(".surfboards__slider_arrows__forward");
var sliderContainer = document.querySelector(".surfboards__slide_container");
var boards = ["images/board.png","images/board.png","images/board.png","images/board.png","images/board.png","images/board.png","images/board.png","images/board.png"];
console.log(document.querySelector(".surfboard__images__current"));
sliderContainer.style.marginLeft = "0px";
sliderBack.onclick = function(){
    sliderCounter--;
    console.log("SMTH");
    sliderContainer.style.marginLeft = parseInt(sliderContainer.style.marginLeft) + 1024 + "px";
}
sliderForward.onclick = function(){
    sliderCounter++;
    console.log("SMTH");
    sliderContainer.style.marginLeft = parseInt(sliderContainer.style.marginLeft) - 1024 + "px";
}

images[0 + (sliderCounter * 3)].onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector(".surfboard__images__current").classList.remove("surfboard__images__current");
    images[0 + (sliderCounter * 3)].classList.add("surfboard__images__current");
    console.log(images[0]);
    board[sliderCounter].src = boards[0 + (sliderCounter * 3)];
}

images[1 + (sliderCounter * 3)].onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector(".surfboard__images__current").classList.remove("surfboard__images__current");
    images[1 + (sliderCounter * 3)].classList.add("surfboard__images__current");
    console.log(images[1]);
    board[sliderCounter].src = boards[1 + (sliderCounter * 3)];
}
images[2 + (sliderCounter * 3)].onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector(".surfboard__images__current").classList.remove("surfboard__images__current");
    images[2 + (sliderCounter * 3)].classList.add("surfboard__images__current");
    console.log(images[2 + (sliderCounter * 3)]);
    board[sliderCounter].src = boards[2 + (sliderCounter * 3)];
}
images[3 + (sliderCounter * 3)].onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector(".surfboard__images__current").classList.remove("surfboard__images__current");
    images[3 + (sliderCounter * 3)].classList.add("surfboard__images__current");
    console.log(images[3 + (sliderCounter * 3)]);
    board[sliderCounter].src = boards[3 + (sliderCounter * 3)];
}
choices[0 + (sliderCounter * 3)].onclick = function(){
    movingline.style.marginLeft = "0px";
    document.querySelectorAll(".surfboards__main__information__choice__current")[0].classList.remove("surfboards__main__information__choice__current");
    this.classList.add("surfboards__main__information__choice__current");
    slider.style.marginLeft = "0px";
}
choices[1 + (sliderCounter * 3)].onclick = function(){
    movingline.style.marginLeft = "100px";
    document.querySelectorAll(".surfboards__main__information__choice__current")[0].classList.remove("surfboards__main__information__choice__current");
    this.classList.add("surfboards__main__information__choice__current");
    slider.style.marginLeft = "-350px";
}
choices[2 + (sliderCounter * 3)].onclick = function(){
    movingline.style.marginLeft = "183px";
    document.querySelectorAll(".surfboards__main__information__choice__current")[0].classList.remove("surfboards__main__information__choice__current");
    this.classList.add("surfboards__main__information__choice__current");
    slider.style.marginLeft = "-700px";
}
```

Comment: знаешь что такое циклы?

Comment: Для начала отладьте код, чтобы он работал как было задумано (сейчас sliderCounter бесполезен). Посмотрите, что можно вынести в стили, чтобы не использовать "магические" оффсеты в скрипте.

Comment: во-первых цикл использовать нельзя, т.к он будет выполняться только один раз, да знаю, что slider counter бесполезен, поторопился. Пока хотелось бы узнать как это дело можно сократить, пробовал setInterval(), не сработало

Comment: `во-первых цикл использовать нельзя, т.к он будет выполняться только один раз,` - один раз для чего? ты навешиваешь событие клика на однотипные блоки... для этого разумно использовать цикл. Или ты думаешь, что один цикл дает один клик?

Comment: Цикл выполняется один раз при загрузке страницы, если хотите более подробно разъяснить мысль напишите отдельно код.

Comment: Лучше узнать понимаешь ли ты сам, что у тебя написано и в чем ты видишь проблему того, что цикл выполняется один раз при загрузке страницы, если ты тут события вешаешь. смысл кода каков, сможешь объяснить?

Comment: Создай функции с параметрами вместо задания параметров в коде функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо за предложенные советы в комментариях. Затупил сильно, да так, что не додумался использовать цикл, вот код:

```
for(var i=0; i< images.length; i++){
    images[i].onclick = function(){ 
        document.querySelector(".surfboard__images__current").classList.remove("surfboard__images__current");
            this.classList.add("surfboard__images__current");
            for(var i =0; i < images.length;; i++){
                if(images[i] == this){
                    console.log(i);
                    board[sliderCounter].src = boards[i];
                }
            }
            console.log(images[i]);
            console.log(boards[i]);
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}
```